# How often does the black market refresh its stock?

Tags: xcom-2

How often does the black market refresh its stock of materials? Is it every month?  I thought it was every mission but it doesn't appear that way, and I tried timing it for a month with very inconsistent results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Black Market refreshes it's inventory after every supply drop.